# Active record get_where() adds spurious backticks

Tags: codeigniter

I have a simple insert and then select:-

```
$q = "this and that between , up to and in the.";

$this->db->insert('data_strings', ['string' => $q]);

print_r($this->db->get_where('data_strings', ['string' => $q])->result());
```

This produces:-

```
Array ( )
```

The reason for this seems to be that when active record compiles the select, it adds unnecessary backticks to the query and we end up with this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM `data_strings`
WHERE `string` = 'this and `that` between `, up` `to` and in the.'
```

It looks like a bug in Codeigniter. Does anybody know if there is a decent work around?

To replicate:

```
$q = "this and that between , up to and in the.";
$this->db->where('string', $q);
echo $this->db->get_compiled_select('data_strings');
```

Comment: clarification: get_where or LIKE ??

Comment: just get_where.

Comment: Replicated on newest version of CI with php 7.1. The problem is visible unless one puts the comma in the "right" place e.g. : "this and that between, up to and in the." no idea why this is happening though.

Comment: But an Insert shouldn't have a where component anyway?

Comment: @Antony he has an *insert* and -then- a *select* ... the issue is with the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that this problem is not just limited to get_where(). This problem also happens with where(). I tested and had the same problem with this:

```
$query = $this->db->where(['string' => $q])
    ->get('data_strings');
```

I also had the same problem with this:

```
$query = $this->db->where('string', $q)
    ->get('data_strings');
```

In the end, the best (and possibly only) work-around is to use CodeIgniter's query bindings feature:

```
$query = $this->db->query('
    SELECT * 
    FROM data_strings
    WHERE string = ? 
', [ $q ] );
```

This full example works as expected:

```
<?php

/*************************************************************

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_strings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

*************************************************************/

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->database();

        $q = " and x between x and ";

        $this->db->insert('data_strings', [
            'string' => $q
        ]);

        $query = $this->db->query('
            SELECT * 
            FROM data_strings
            WHERE string = ? 
        ', [ $q ] );

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump( $query->result() );
            echo '</pre>';
        }
        else
        {
            // SELECT * FROM `data_strings` WHERE `string` = 'this and `that` between `, up` `to` and in the.'
            echo $this->db->last_query();
        }
    }

}
```

Please note: I was using the mysqli driver. Fresh CodeIgniter install. Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I agree, it looks like the only easy way around this issue is to use raw sql queries. I'm going to have to find another solution however as there is no way I can switch over from using active record in my project without *serious* delays. I'll wait a few days and if I don't get a solution to the root problem, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Narf just made a revision to CodeIgniter that should fix the issue: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/7dd6f14073c109a3227d78e30780ab79117bda42

If you were willing to pull down those changes, seems like it would work. And it would be forward compatible with your next CodeIgniter update.

Comment: Nice! I'll check it out in a bit. Thanks.